# saving background color on localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I got the data stored on my `localStorage` and display them in table format with each row having a button. What I want to do now is, when the button is clicked I want it to change the background color to another color and when the page refreshes the button persists its color state.

Here is my code

```js
// here i will be the data in form of table
// my algorithm comes here
// this function will get data from the localstorage
const get_todos = ()=>{
  let todos = new Array();
  let todos_str = localStorage.getItem("todo");
  if(todos_str !== null){
    todos = JSON.parse(todos_str);
  }
  return todos;
}
//this function will show the data in the localstorage in table format
const show = ()=>{
  let todos = get_todos();
  let text = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++){
      let allData = todos[i];
      let eventName = allData.Eventname;
      let location = allData.Location;
      let date = allData.Date;
      text += "<tr>";
      text += "<td>" + eventName + "</td>";
      text += "<td>" + location + "</td>";
      text += "<td>" + date + "</td>";
      text += "<td>" + "<button class='buttons' type='button'>Pending</button>" + "</td>";
      text += "<td>" + "<i id='remove' class='fas fa-trash-alt btndelete'></i>" + "</td></tr>";

  }
  //the data gotten from the localstorage will be here
  let table = document.querySelector("#table > tbody");
  table.innerHTML = text;
  //this is where the button background color will change
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    let thead = document.querySelector("#thead");
    let buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".buttons"));
    thead.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
      if(e.target.className === "buttons"){
        let index = buttons.indexOf(e.target);
        changeBackground(e, index);
      }
    });
    buttons.forEach(btn, index =>{
      btn.className = sessionStorage.getItem('background${index}') || 'buttons';
      
    });
  });
  const changeBackground = (e, index)=>{
    e.target.className += "change";
    sessionStorage.setItem(background${index}, e.target.className);

  }
  
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
  show();
});
```

Comment: Your code have an syntax error `sessionStorage.setItem(background${index}, e.target.className);`. Do you miss something?

Comment: what i mean is localstorage and also if there is a better way to that please do it and share me the

Comment: It depends on your application. Since you save the "todos" locally, I assume you want the application to be used offline. If that is right, then is it the best way.

Answer (score 1):

There is few errors in your code:

**First**:

```
btn.className = sessionStorage.getItem('background${index}') || 'buttons';
```

Should be:

```
btn.className = sessionStorage.getItem(`background${index}`) || 'buttons';
```

because you are create a string using [Template literals (Template strings)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

**Second**:

```
e.target.className += "change";
```

Should be:

```
e.target.className += " change";
```

You have to add space when concatenate strings, or else in your case it will not provide the intended behavior, since your code will add `change` class name to the previous class as one word.

**Third**:

```
sessionStorage.setItem(background${index}, e.target.className);
```

Should be:

```
sessionStorage.setItem(`background${index}`, e.target.className);
```

In your question you are talking about [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) but you are 
using [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage), Still not sure if this what you want, so if you want it to be [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) just replace [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) with [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

```
// here i will be the data in form of table
// my algorithm comes here
// this function will get data from the localstorage
const get_todos = ()=>{
  let todos = new Array();
  let todos_str = localStorage.getItem("todo");
  if(todos_str !== null){
    todos = JSON.parse(todos_str);
  }
  return todos;
}
//this function will show the data in the localstorage in table format
const show = ()=>{
  let todos = get_todos();
  let text = "";
  for(let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++){
      let allData = todos[i];
      let eventName = allData.Eventname;
      let location = allData.Location;
      let date = allData.Date;
      text += "<tr>";
      text += "<td>" + eventName + "</td>";
      text += "<td>" + location + "</td>";
      text += "<td>" + date + "</td>";
      text += "<td>" + "<button class='buttons' type='button'>Pending</button>" + "</td>";
      text += "<td>" + "<i id='remove' class='fas fa-trash-alt btndelete'></i>" + "</td></tr>";

  }
  //the data gotten from the localstorage will be here
  let table = document.querySelector("#table > tbody");
  table.innerHTML = text;
  //this is where the button background color will change
window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    let thead = document.querySelector("#thead");
    let buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".buttons"));
    thead.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
      if(e.target.className === "buttons"){
        let index = buttons.indexOf(e.target);
        changeBackground(e, index);
      }
    });
    buttons.forEach(btn, index =>{
      btn.className = localStorage.getItem(`background${index}`) || 'buttons';

    });
  });
  const changeBackground = (e, index)=>{
    e.target.className += " change";
    localStorage.setItem(`background${index}`, e.target.className);
  }

}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ()=>{
  show();
});
```